# If filesize > X copy to A elseif copy to B in Automator

Tags: macos, mac, automator

I would like to create a workflow which on "Ask for Finder Items", once selected and the filtered query is found I want the file to be copied to one of two locations, where it goes depends on size.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a shell script action like this:

```
for f in "$@"; do
    [[ $(stat -f %z "$f") -ge 50000 ]] && cp "$f" /tmp/ || cp "$f" ~/Desktop/
done
```

Pass input has to be set to as arguments. `stat -f %z` (format size) prints file size in bytes. `du -sk "$f" | cut -f1` (specified folder, kibibyte blocks) would print the size of the contents of folders.